# XPATH: .select_by_visible_text not working

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

This seems like a really trivial problem, but for some reason my .select_by_visible_text isn't working on my form. Here is the XML layout:

```
<label for="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2945768361,4093122127418558670,multipleChoice)" class="fb-form-element-label" data-test-form-element-label="">
    
  <span class="t-14 fb-form-element-label__title--is-required" data-test-form-element-label-title="true">
      At the time of applying, are you 18 years of age or older?
  </span>

    <span class="visually-hidden" data-test-form-element-required="true">
      Required
    </span>

<!---->
<!---->
  </label>
<div class="fb-dropdown" data-test-dropdown="">
  <select id="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2945768361,4093122127418558670,multipleChoice)" class="  fb-dropdown__select" aria-describedby="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2945768361,4093122127418558670,multipleChoice)-error-message" data-test-fb-dropdown-select="">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>

    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
</div>
```

My code is successful at locating all xpaths, and I do not believe it is an xpath issue. However, here is my code for reference:

```
form_choice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[starts-with(@for, "urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement")][contains(@for, "multipleChoice")]')
for link in form_choice:
    fill = False
    try:
        link.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(., "18") or contains(., "applying") or contains(., "job")]')
        link.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::div[1]//select').select_by_visible_text("Yes")
        fill = True
        form = True
    except:
        pass
```

Please keep in mind that my xpaths are formatted like this because the element names are never constant. It finds the correct elements anyway, so that shouldn't be the issue. Strangely, if I put in link.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::div[1]//select').click() , it clicks the correct form element. However no amount of revision has been able to get the program to select the proper drop-down option, including using .click() before or after the .select_by_visible_text command.

Thanks in advance for your help!

(Edit) After playing around some more, I've discovered that I am unable to select anything from the drop-down menu by any means, not just select_by_visible_text . The form element is clearly located and selected. I've also tried waiting_until_clickable . It's all open and ready for the code. The only issue is getting it to pick an option.

Answer (score 1):

`select_by_visible_text` is a method of Select class instance. Try

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
...
drop_down = Select(link.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::div[1]//select'))
drop_down.select_by_visible_text("Yes")
```